# Bluetooth wireless headphones will only change volume from the headphones and not the computer

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, headphones

When I change the volume on my Windows 10 computer using the keys to change the volume, it doesn't change the volume for my JBL Tune 750BTNC wireless headphones but the headphones in built volume changer is able to change its own volume but doesn't effect the volume of my PC if I disconnect it.

Changing the volume on my PC to 0 does mute the volume of my headphones but if my headphones are set to 20 and my computer 100, my headphones will play at a volume of 20. If I then disconnect the headphones it will play at 100.

Answer (score 1):

Please try if the following method was helpful:

1. Open Windows Registry (regedit.exe).
2. Locate to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Bluetooth\Audio\AVRCP\CT`
3. Create `REG_DWORD` `DisableAbsoluteVolume` and set it's value to `1`.
4. Restart your PC for changes to take affect.